# Rename adb to android-adb

Tags: discussion, bug, suggested-edits

Since this is about UNIX, I would expect that the tag [adb](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adb) refers to the **advanced debugger** written by Stephen Bourne in the mid 1970 as the standard debugger for UNIX.

This tag currently however is misused for a third party program from Google for Android.

To avoid confusion, I propose to rename `adb` to `android-adb`.

Comment: If you format your tags as [tag:adb] instead of `adb` (`[tag:adb]` instead of `adb`), it always people to click on it to quickly go to that tag pages to see the issue themselves quicker (note that it will show the same as tag formatting when used in a question or answer, but not in a comment)

Comment: I am not sure whether I understand you correctly. I beleve however that it would help if there was a correct `adb` tag created at the same time when the old one is renamed. Here is the man page from UNIX V7 https://www.unix.com/man-page/v7/1/adb/ and here is the man page for `adb` on recent Solaris http://schillix.sourceforge.net/man/man1/adb.1.html that still exists but is now based on an enhanced version of the debugger called `mdb`.

Comment: "ADB" clearly refers to the [Apple Desktop Bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Desktop_Bus).

Comment: So you believe this existed before 1975?

Comment: We have to walk a fine line between the tags being sufficiently convenient (short) and obvious (common usage) that askers can choose the right ones, and the inevitable ambiguity when programs of the same name come and go in an almost 50-year-old ecosystem. That means  `rsh` is used for questions about the remote shell rather than restricted shell, and `vi` is used overwhelmingly for vim questions.

Comment: I don't use `vi` or `vim` (I rather use my own `ved` since 1982), but I frequently use `adb` the advanced debugger from Stephen Bourne since it is usable even on stripped binaries - even with names taken from the shared library interface.